# Can't read file in__init__

Tags: python, class

I am a newbe to Python.
I have tried to create a class, named ic0File.

Here is what I get when I use it (Python 3.1)

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/remote/us01home15/ldagan/python/')
>>> import ic0File
>>> a=ic0File.ic0File('as_client/nohpp.ic0')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "ic0File.py", line 7, in __init__
    print ("".join(self.lines))
NameError: global name 'infile' is not defined
```

The class code is:

```
class ic0File:
    def __init__(self,filename):
        self.infile = open(filename, 'r')
        import sys
        import re
        self.lines=self.infile.readlines() #reading the lines
        print ("".join(self.lines)
```

Thanks,

Comment: I doubt this is the actual code.  Please update your question with the actual code that created the error.  Also, what version of Python are you using?  And what tutorial are you following?

Comment: The code you've given doesn't quite seem to correspond with the error you're getting. In particular, line 7 quoted by Python doesn't even contain the identifier `infile`, so that might mean that you changed the source file *after* loading it into the Python interpreter with `import ic0File`. I recommend exiting the Python interpreter, and trying again.

Comment: Indeed, I have just tested it and it works fine.

Comment: WOW. That was a fast reply.
I am new to this site too.
Just moved from PERL & TCL.
Is there a way to replace older class definition with new class definition w/o exiting the interpeter? I have done something similar in TCL.

Comment: @Lior yes. just redefine the class. It can be a pain though. I normally re-execute the file that the class is defined in using `python -i foo.py` which gives you interpreter access after the module runs. when you do this, `__name__ == '__main__' is `True` so you can run testing code.  I just googled http://effbot.org/pyfaq/tutor-what-is-if-name-main-for.htm so you can read about it. put your testing code under the check for `__name__`

Comment: @aaronasterling: you've missed the point.

Comment: @katrielalex perhaps. if you `import foo` then you have to prefix everything with `foo`. if you `from foo import *` then `reload(foo)` is useless. better have everything in `__main__` by running the source file and putting setup code for live poking around after da kine at the end of your source file. Just my two cents.

Comment: Well, yes, but the point was that the OP wanted to reload a module from within the interpreter "w/o exiting the interpreter". If using a different workflow then there are different solutions.

Comment: Please fix the title or the question.  Or consider closing the question.  The actual question and the posted code and the solutions make very little sense together.  How does this help someone else who has the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

To reload a module (e.g. if you have modified the code), use [`reload()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reload). In your case:

```
reload( ic0file )
```

In Python 3, `reload` was moved to the [`imp`](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/imp.html?highlight=reload#imp.reload) library:

```
import imp
imp.reload( ic0file )
```

Answer (score 0):

As other users have pointed out, the code that actually raised that exception would be helpful, but my guess is that you're trying to access the `infile` attribute of a `ic0File` as if it was actually a variable.

You've probably written something like this:

```
self.lines = infile.readlines() #reading the lines
```

instead of:

```
self.lines = self.infile.readlines() #reading the lines
```

in one of the methods of `ic0File`. Unlike in other languages, object attributes don't become local variables in said object's methods.